# Requests is not working in one of my DJANGO project

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, python-requests

I am having trouble with requests package and I tried my best to resolve this problem.

Problem- requests is not working in one of my Django Projects. It returns 403 Forbidden. But the same code is working on my other Django Project (Same laptop with same internet connection, but different virtual environment).

So, because of this I am not able to use requests package in one of my existing Django Project.

Here is the code: This is the demo code which I will run on two Django Project with two different virtual environment.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from django.shortcuts import render
​
# from .models import RequestData
​
​
def home(request):
    data = []
    urls = [
        "https://api.github.com/search/repositories",
        "https://www.dataquest.io",
        "https://www.python.org",
        "https://api.github.com/events"
    ]
    for url in urls:
        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
        if soup.title:
            data.append(str(soup.title))
        else:
            data.append("No Title")
    return render(request, "requester/index.html", {'data': data})
```

Here is my HTML part:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% for dat in data  %}
      <li>{{dat}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

Here are my responses from both the Django project.

First (Which have problem)

[image]

---

Second(Without any problem)

[image]

Also, I tried with different versions of requests package but still have the same problem.

Comment: diffrent results in different environments or different results in different sites?

Comment: Different results in different django project with different virtual environment. But running on same machine.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the same urls.py too ?
I can see a difference (tst vs test)
You could be calling another function.

Comment: Yes, same code even in the urls.py . It is just a demo to show my problem.There is no difference in both urls.py code for that function.

Comment: I am not calling other function or I did not pass any other arguments.

Comment: I mean that everything looks fine except the url you use to call the function, try to navigate to http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/ instead of /tst/

Comment: Sir,  I have created different url for both the project. /tst and /test points to the same code. Naming does not matter. I am not scraping these websites. I am just showing my problem by using those websites.